# How to get IsActivated notification from the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: wpf, events, popup, taskbar

My specific issue is not being able to close a WPF Popup/Flyout when anything on the Taskbar is clicked.  I have been able handle its closing from just about any other object, but the Taskbar remains a mystery.

I have looked into various ways to get Taskbar information (such as SHAppBarMessage), but it seems I can only know two specific states about the Taskbar, neither of which help me.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Window.Deactivated event is triggered by clicking the taskbar.

Comment: Thank you.  I will test this tomorrow.

Comment: This didn't work for our application.  Our application always remains open, and doesn't steal the focus (or register an Activation event).  We need to find a different way than using the Window's Deactivation event.